# Combobox assign null if value does not exist in itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, mvvm-light

I have a Datagrid, and upon double clicking the selected row, an edit screen is launched.
On this edit screen, there are combobox, whose value is binded to the selected row in the grid.
Sometimes, the value assigned to the combobox does not exist in the combobox itemSource, so the display on the combobox is empty, but the value is not null.
How can I update the value of the selected item, to be null if the value does not exist in the itemsource collection.

[image]

In the above scenario, Since, the second screen is bound to the Selected item on the first sreen, the SelectedValue for City is "Los Angeles" and the Display is Empty. 
But since "Los Angeles" does not exist in the collection,  SelectedValue should be null.

Comment: Have you tried using a converter?

Comment: Haven't tried. What shall the converter do?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to set the *ItemsSource* of the combobox to the list (example: "DeviceNameList") and set the *SelectedItem* of this combobox to a variable that matches the type of elements inside your list (SelectedDeviceName).

Now when you load your edit screen, it will have bound the list to the combobox and display the variable you set.

You have to write some code to check if the selected item occurs in the list and if not you can set the value to zero.

**Example:**

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DeviceNameList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDeviceName}" />
```

Code to set the selectedItem:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets SelectedDeviceName.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<string> DeviceNameList
    {
         get
        {
           return mDeviceNameList;
        }

        set
        {
            mDeviceNameList = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets SelectedDeviceName.
    /// </summary>
    public string SelectedDeviceName
    {
        get
        {
            return mSelectedDeviceName;
        }

        set
        {
            mSelectedDeviceName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDeviceName");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event PropertyChanged
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        /// <summary>
    /// Function NotifyPropertyChanged
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">
    /// The property.
    /// </param>
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Enrico, thanks, but this part I have already figured out. I want the portion where I can check if the selectedValue exist in the collection.

Comment: I would suggest something like *foreach* to go through the list and then when current item does not equal something in the list you assign it zero?

Answer (score 0):

Converters are used to translate the data in the binding
to the desired result. (Allowing incompatible types to be matched between source and target).

A similar question on converter used between a combobox and itemsource is in here:

[Use converter on bound items in combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448862/use-converter-on-bound-items-in-combobox)

and you can read more aboud converters in general here:

http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

In this case, the converter should be placed on selectedItem property of the combo.

**EDIT:**

I've played a bit with a sample of code, and registeed to the selection changed event in the combo box. this event is only triggered if the source for the selection item yields a selection which is valid for the combo box.
So now I return to my original suggestion which should work:
In the converter , check the incoming value against the list of all values of the combobox items.
If it does not exist , the converter needs to let the combo know it should set its selected item to null. While I'm sure there are more simple and elegant ways to do this (I'm not a WPF expert) this should do the trick.

Another lead on how to hook the converter with the control is using multibinding:

[Can a WPF converter access the control to which it is bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454726/can-a-wpf-converted-access-the-control-to-which-it-is-bound)

Comment: I'm not seeing how a ValueConverter might help here. Can you elaborate it a bit please?

Comment: I don't think a converter will work here. I want to set the selected value to null if it does not exist in the itemsSource Collection

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. but if you bind your selected item, than you can use the converter to check if the new incoming value is present in the current values of the control. if so - use it. otherwise- set it to null.

Comment: @xaria , does this make sense to you?

Comment: @omerschleifer No, it doesn't help either

Comment: @xaria , I've edited my answer. I'm preaty sure it should work, though it isn't very clean I'll admit.